# a variable is being set as Nan at one place, but correctly at another location

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the below code, I'am trying to read a tsv file which contains name and value pairs, to draw a bar graph using d3.js.

Before the below code I have already set the y = d3.scale.linear.range().

Why is it that when I'am, setting the,`rect.attr('y',height - barHeight);` y is set as NaN, while here `var rect = bar.append('rect')
                .attr('width', barWidth-1)
                .attr('height', barHeight);` the rectangle height is being set correctly.

I have set the height and width value before this function. They are not undefined.

The problem is with the computation `height - barHeight`, if I just give it as `.attr('y',barHeight);`, it is setting the y attribute of the rectangle.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');


var width = 960;
var height = 500;
svg.attr('height', height)
        .attr('width', width);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0,500]);

d3.tsv("./src/src.tsv", typeCast,

function (error, array)
    {
        y.domain([0, d3.max(array, function (d){

            return d.value;

        })]);

        var barWidth = width / array.length;

        var barHeight = function (d)
        {
            console.log(y(d.value));
            return y(d.value);
        }


        var bar = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(array)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', function (d, i){

                return "translate("+i * barWidth+")";

            });


        var rect = bar.append('rect')
            .attr('width', barWidth-1)
            .attr('height', barHeight);

        rect.attr('y', height - barHeight);


    }
    );
```

Please help me with setting the y attribute of the rectangle.

Comment: did you try after `.attr('height', barHeight)`, having another `.attr('y', height - barHeight);`

Comment: The problem is with the computation `height - barHeight`, if I just give it as `.attr('y',barHeight);`, it is setting it right.

Comment: @ivenki94 where do you set the variable `height`?

Comment: I have set it before this function is being defined.
`var width = 960, height  = 500;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused, because your `barHeight` is a function.

```
var barHeight = function (d)
```

When using it like `.attr('height', barHeight)` it will give the correct value, because `.attr()` accepts a function as the second argument, which will be executed and return the value.

The second usage should be like

```
rect.attr('y', function(d) { return height - barHeight(d); });
```

Comment: yes, I know its a function that takes a parameter d, how do you pass the parameter d. d is undefined right?. d is very row from the tsv file being read by d3. I'am not call it explicitly call it as barHeight(d). It gives me an error d is undefined. 

While d3 passes it as it parses every row of the tsv file being read.

Comment: That is what I told you in my previous comment, I cannot call the function explicitly like that, it gives an error d is undefined.

Comment: If the first usage like `.attr('height', barHeight)` works fine, my proposed solution should do as well. It's basically the same thing since `d` is passed to `barHeight()`. Did you try the **exact** line I wrote down? If that doesn't work, I don't have a clue. Maybe you should put together a JSFiddle to play around with.

Comment: Thanks man it totally worked. I thought you suggested just this `height - barHeight(d)`. Got it buddy.

Answer (score 0):

The variable height isn't defined, so `height - barHeight` is `undefined - Number`, which is `NaN`. Set the variable `height` correctly